# Actual value vs Display value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am worked on ruby on rails. In that i have doubt in dateTime filter, what means I need to display one date and send another date to backend for query.

Display date is date which is user entered. Another date is date which is UTC date conversion of date which is user entered. For this i am using hidden field in forms and used the JavaScript.

The form is below

```
.form-group
    = f.label :from_time, "From", class: 'sr-only'
    .input-group.date#from_time.hidden_on_ltie8{ style: "width:180px;", data: { behaviour: 'booking-filter-datetimepicker' } }
      // For time zone conversion
      = f.hidden_field :from_time
      = text_field_tag :from_time_display, '' ,value: @booking_filter_form.from_time, placeholder: 'From time', class: 'form-control' , id: "from_time_id", onkeydown: "event.preventDefault()"
```

The JS is below

```
$('#filter_id_account').on("click",function (event) {
     if($("#from_time_id").val()){
     var date1 = $("#from_time_id").val();
     $("#filter_forms_booking_from_time").val(time_conversion(date1));
     }
     else
     {
     $("#filter_forms_booking_from_time").val("");
     }

});
```

Here filter_id_account is button id, from_time_id is text field id,  filter_forms_booking_from_time is hidden field id.

But i am need of only use the text field. Here I am using only text field. But while click the button "Filter", it's loading and on that loading from time field shows the actual value and after loading it display the display value.  Please anybody tell some idea for this.

The below code is tome zone conversion function.

```
var zone = moment.tz.guess();
function time_conversion(date) {
    out = moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
    var utc_time = moment.tz(out, zone).tz('UTC').format();
    return utc_time;
}
```

Here i am using the moment.tz.guess() for getting time zone of browser.

The form button is

```
    = f.submit 'Filter', class: 'btn btn-default', id: "filter_id_account"
```

Using text field is

```
.form-group
        = f.label :from_time, "From", class: 'sr-only'
          // For time zone conversion
          = f.text_field :from_time,value: @booking_filter_form.from_time, placeholder: 'From time', class: 'form-control' , id: "from_time_id", onkeydown: "event.preventDefault()"
```

The JS is below

```
$('#filter_id_account').on("click",function (event) {
     if($("#from_time_id").val()){
     var date1 = $("#from_time_id").val();
     $("#from_time_id").val(time_conversion(date1));
     }
     else
     {
     $("#from_time_id").val("");
     }

});
```

So anybody tell some idea to use only text field without any loading time issue. And also please tell whether moment.tz.guess() function is working on production correctly????

Comment: @Mark Merritt Did you mean like onload function??

Comment: Take care in spelling Javascript. http://javascriptisnotjava.com/